# XSD How To

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

**Background:**

We have an application that has been in the works for over a year by a third party company and looks like we will be maintaining this in house from now on. For the most part i am very competent i can handle 99% of any issues that come up.

In this project there is an XSD file acts as a pass through to a bunch of stored procedures on a SQL Server 2005 box.

**Questions:**

- Can the the XSD file be generated
  from the database, if so how is this
  done?
- Are these files hard to maintain if a
  stored procedure is changed on the
  database does a new XSD file need to
  be generated or can it be updated
  manually?
- Best practices with dealing with
  these files?

I understand that this is a big question but i want to fully understand this before i take of the project next Tuesday. I am not sure if i will get much information out of the original developer about this.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a small sample of the XSD to give us a better grasp of the current solution. (Could this be a similar, only hand-rolled approach, to how Hibernate handles custom sprocs I am wondering?)

Comment: I understand what you are saying now, I got confused with the singular "an XSD file" and plural "bunch of sprocs"

Comment: XSD cannot be "a pass through", since XSD is "documetation" for data and not transport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called **Strongly Typed DataSets**.

> Can the the XSD file be generated from the database, if so how is this done?

Yes, open it or add a new dataset to your project, open server explorer from visual studio and connect to your database. Drag'n drop your SP or table.

> Are these files hard to maintain if a stored procedure is changed on the database does a new XSD file need to be generated or can it be updated manually?

Yes it need to be generated when the source changes. You can do it by deleting the related table or sp from xsd, and then adding it again.

Some visual tutorials about Strongly Typed DataSets :

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/15/435498.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20210608183519/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/020806-1.aspx

Comment: Ok that 1% is all good to go thanks to you. At moments like this i wish i had the ability to bump you up +5 more.

Comment: thank you ! I remember when I first read about Strongly Typed DataSets :)